# How to get leftBarButtonItem width?

Tags: ios, swift, width, uibarbuttonitem, searchbar

I want to make a custom search bar in navigationBar ([screenshot](http://oi57.tinypic.com/a9xqac.jpg)). I have put a UIBarButton to the left side of navigationBar in my storyboard. But searchBar will be generated from code because I don't know how to make that searchBar.

So I want to put it right after leftBarButtonItem.width +- 10/20 pixels. How to get leftBarButtonItem.width, in viewDidLoad it is zero.

Is there a way to do this? Or maybe someone can tell be better way how to create that searchBar and put it in navigationBar.

Comment: You have to put your searchbar in the navigation bar's `titleView`.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Why not in the navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem? And what frame should it be to stay near leftBarButtonItem with some margin?

Comment: it' android' design,  iOS doesn't suit it. But maybe you want put searchbar in titleView

Comment: @Paruru my customer want it to be like on screenshot, so I have no variants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: code]

[image: on sim]

you can change the button's width to set the positon